# Unable to create a subkey in registry

Tags: c#, registry

The following code does run without error and with exception. However, the subkey is NOT created. Not sure what's wrong. Thanks!

```
try
{
    var stupPath = "\"" + folder + "\\My.exe\" \"currentuser\"  \"" + folder + "\"";
    var subkeyHKLM = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components", true);
    if (subkeyHKLM == null) return;
    subkeyHKLM.CreateSubKey("MyAddIn");
    subkeyHKLM.SetValue("StubPath", stupPath, RegistryValueKind.ExpandString);
    subkeyHKLM.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Update:

I changed to the following and now it works but the key is created in HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components

```
            var newKey = subkeyHKLM.CreateSubKey("MyAddIn");
            if (newKey != null)
            {
                newKey.SetValue("StubPath", stupPath, RegistryValueKind.ExpandString);
            }
            subkeyHKLM.Close();
```

Comment: Well you're swallowing all exceptions, so you wouldn't see any anyway. Note that you're also returning if the relevant subkey doesn't exist. Have you debugged through the code to see how far it gets? We can't tell, but you can...

Comment: Did you check if your key has been created under WOW64 key?

Comment: I debugged through and see no exception occurred but no key is created either

Comment: I found it in WOW6432Node, but only the key MyAddIn, the name "StubPath" is not created.  So strange